# Gulp watch doesn't do anything

Tags: javascript, css, gulp

I'm trying to use Watch to compile my SASS files, but it doesn't work.

**Package.json**

```
"author": "José Ramón Rico Lara",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "gulp": "^4.0.2",
    "gulp-concat": "^2.6.1",
    "gulp-imagemin": "^7.1.0",
    "gulp-notify": "^3.2.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^4.1.0",
    "gulp-webp": "^4.0.1"
  }
}
```

**Gulpfile.js**

```
const { series, src, watch, dest, parallel } = require('gulp');
const sass = require('gulp-sass')
const webp = require('gulp-webp');

const paths = {
    scss: 'src/scss/**/*.scss',
    js: 'src/js/**/*.js'
}

function css() {
    return src(paths.scss)
        .pipe(sass())
        .pipe(dest('./build/css'))
}

function javascript() {
    return src(paths.js)
        .pipe(concat('bundle.js'))
        .pipe(dest('./build/js'))
}

function watchArchivos() {
    watch(paths.scss, css); // * = La carpeta actual - ** = Todos los archivos con esa extensión
    watch(paths.js, javascript);
}

exports.css = css;
exports.javascript = javascript;
exports.watchArchivos = watchArchivos;

exports.default = series(css, javascript, watchArchivos);
```

In the console it says, that the code is running and there isn't any issue, but when I change any file it doesn't compile it.

Comment: Are your paths relative to the location of this gulpfile.js?  And you could try: `watch(paths.js, series(javascript));` and same for other watch.  Also, you will want to use `gulp-dart-sass` instead of `gulp-sass`, the later can't handle `@use` for example.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell there are no gulp.tasks... in example

```
gulp.task('watch', function() {
  gulp.watch('public/assets/css/*.css', gulp.series('clean-css', 'pack-css'));
});
```

Also in the file you've supplied there's just exports, and you're not calling " watchArchivos".

Comment: Don't need `gulp.task` in gulp v4.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem, the watching task never got executed, the first task in this case (browser) was a browser sync instance, in my case the browser task was asynchronous, so I had to use asyn / await and everything worked fine.
From:

```js
function browser() {
  browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: PATHS.output,
    },
  });
}
exports.default = series (browser, watching);
```

To

```js
async function browser() {
  await browserSync.init({
    server: {
      baseDir: PATHS.output,
    },
  });
}
```